# Ajax update takes suddenly 30+ seconds instead of 0.5~2 seconds

Tags: performance, jsf, ajax-update

i'm creating a jsf 2.2 web application with wildfly 8.2 and primefaces which is working very well. 
but since two or three days there is a strange ajax change event loading behavior.

i'm using a h:selectOneMenu component with a f:ajax change event for loading and refreshing a p:outputPanel. the problem is that if the change event is fired the data is loading correctly and are available within milliseconds but the refreshing event on the jsf view takes 30 seconds and more. 
i don't know why. 
a few days ago the components were refreshed within 0.5 to 2 seconds.
i changed nothing on this component or view.

i debugged the view controller and can see that the dataset is available right now but in the firebug, the post request is working further and after 30 seconds and more the result is showing on the jsf view.

has or had anyone the same problem ?
how can i debug the javascript from the f:ajax change event ?

hope someone can help me

Comment: Probably, IDE related. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project and also cleaning your browser cache.

Comment: I cleaned the browser cache and the eclipse IDE but it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days of debugging i found the error. 
For all they are interested in. 
On the view is a h:textLabel which is filled with some data. if the ajax change event is fired this field get new data too, but i don't know why if there is a special sign like "\n" in this field it takes very long to update this field on the view.

Comment: It would be nice if you could come up with a MCVE reproducing exactly this problem in a scratchpad project with everything set to default. It sounds much like the ajax response content length is incorrectly calculated and set on response header and thus the webbrowser is expecting more data and waiting until timeout. This in turn indicates a possible bug in the JSF implementation being used.